# Regex: Workaround for PHP's look-behind fixed-length assert limitation

Tags: php, regex, assert

I'm trying to understand more about look-around asserts and I found [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/172496/regex-negative-matching-trouble), where their solution is supposed to work in some engines but not PHP's, because of PHP's requiring the look-behind assert to be fixed-length.

What I want is to make the same scenario work in PHP or at least know if it's possible at all.

I tried to reduce the regex rules explanation, so it's not the same as in the thread I mention above, but it follows the same principle.

Need to match a string built in three parts:

- Starts with any number of alphanumeric characters
- Does not contain "abc-" followed by between 3 and 5 numbers and/or hyphens
- Ends with ".htm" or ".html"

So, these would match:

- xxxyz-123.html
- xx123-abc.htm
- xxabc123.html
- xxabc-123-45.htm

But these would NOT match:

- xxabc-4324.htm
- xxabc-1-2.html
- xxac-12-34.txt
- xxabc-12345.htm

I've been trying with some variations of the regex pattern below but it's not working - this particular case because of the fixed-length limitation:

`.*(?<!abc-[\d-]{3,5})\.htm[^l]?$`

I also used different test strings and forgot about the 3-5 range part, focusing only on exactly , say, 3 numbers and/or hyphens, and used the regex below, and it still doesn't work, which is why I decided to ask for help on this:

`.*(?<!abc-[\d-]{3})\.htm[^l]?$`

Could anyone of you regex gurus help me out here?

**Edit**

This is my testing PHP code:

```
$regex = "/^(?!.*abc-[\d-]{3,5})[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.html?$/";

foreach ( $matching2 as $k => $v ) {
    $matches = preg_match( $regex, $v );

    echo '"', $v, '"', ( $matches != 0 ) ? ' matches' : ' doesn\'t match', '<br />';
}
```

Comment: the example doesn't need any lookaround assertions. It would if you had dependencies on the three parts.

Comment: How about `xyz-123_45%20_67.htm` - match or not?

Comment: match, because it doesn't have the abc-nnn[nn] part before the .htm extension

Comment: @chris not sure I understand your statement... could you please explain further?

Comment: ^..*?[^a][[^b][^c][^-][^0-9-]{3,5}\.htm(l){0.1} that's generic regex, don't know if it's exactly php style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to need to look at that in reverse? Why not just use a lookahead?

```
^(?!.*abc-[\d-]{3,5}[^\d-])[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.html?$
```

This will simply start looking at the beginning of the string and the lookahead tries to find the disallowed string anywhere (`.*`) in the string. If it does, the lookahead makes the pattern fail. This also include the requirement, that the string consists only of alphanumerics and hyphens.

This is by the way the same solution that is used for the question you linked. Perl cannot cope with variable-length lookbehinds either. **Only** .NET can.

Another note: if you ever encounter an example where you actually **do need** a variable-length lookbehind (but not a variable-length lookahead)... reverse the string (and the pattern, too, of course). ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't match the fourth string, which it should... I added an edit to show my testing code if needed

Comment: @andrux right. however your requirement says "Does not contain "abc-" followed by between 3 and 5 numbers and/or hyphens". Which is the case in the fourth example. Could you please clarify that? Why is example 4 in set 1 matched, but example 2 in set 2 fails?

Comment: Yes, the fourth string is `xxabc-123-45.htm`, and it should be matched because the "abc-" string is followed by 6 numbers or hyphens, it should stop after 5

Comment: @andrux there you go. now the lookahead will try to find 3-5 of those characters, that are followed by a character that is not in this class. note that you could use another negative lookahead for this, but since your string has to end in `\.html?` there will always be some character, so there is no need for a negative lookahead

Comment: Why you do not allow other characters? Consider `xx-abc-123-456_file.htm`

Comment: @Ωmega I wasn't quite sure about the "starts with alphanumeric characters" requirement. Due to the plural I thought it might mean that there should be only alphanumeric characters until the file extension. Hopefully your comment on the question will clarify this.

Comment: I am not sure as well, that's why I am asking both of you... Maybe you are right, but then OP should make it clear in his/her question.

Comment: The parts I'm most interested in are number 2 and 3, the starting of the string - either alphanumeric or not - was just so we don't focus in the start of the string, but in the abc- + numeric range + extension

Comment: @m.buettner it does work, thanks! I just don't understand why does it need the `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` part, since after the "abc-nnn[nn]" part the very next part is the extension... could you explain that?

Comment: @andrux the lookahead is just that... a lookahead... it does not actually advance the engine's position in the search string. i.e. it does not consume any characters. once we are done with the lookahead, and see that the pattern does not fail because of the requirement inside the lookahead, the engine jumps back to where the lookahead started (the beginning of the string). now we need to match our actual file name (without the extension). this is where you can make changes to which characters should be allowed in total. hence, Ωmega's question

Comment: since you allow more than just letters, digits and hyphens (according to your comment on the question) this part could be loosened, as Ωmega did in his answer (only requiring an alphanumeric as the first character and then allowing arbitrary characters after that)

Comment: ok, I'll need to keep testing to get a grip on this, but your answers worked ok, I just need to really understand them :s thanks, guys!

Comment: hey, @m.buettner, I got it, thanks for the explanation, I just had to re read and give it some thought... thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for regex pattern

```
^(?!.*abc-[\d-]{3,5}[^\d-])[A-Za-z0-9].*[.]html?$
```

Comment: not sure, but isn't `[^\d-]` a double negation? because it's inside the `(?!` part

Comment: @andrux I explained that in the 5th comment (counting all comments) on my answer. and yes it is in some sense a double negative, because that is what we need.

Comment: you're right, I didn't see that part.... so, I see what you're saying, but it doesn't make sense the way I see it - although it works the way you wrote it and it doesn't work the way I intended to modify it according to my logic...... of course, my logic's wrong, so I'll just have to keep looking into it....