# preg_split regex lookback for multiple matches

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-split, lookbehind

The goal of my regex is to split on any unicode whitespace, excluding newline and ensure that that newline character is appended to the previous non unicode whitespace character. Currently I am seeing this work, but only for single whitespace characters before the \n.

Using my current Regex:

```
    $data  = "the\nquick\n brown fox jumped     \nover the lazy dog.";
    $tokenized = preg_split("~(?<=\n)|\p{Z}+(?!\n)~u", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Current Result (I have added \n where the "\n" character is present):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => the\n

            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => quick\n

            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => brown
            [1] => 11
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => fox
            [1] => 17
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => jumped
            [1] => 21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  \n
            [1] => 31
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => over
            [1] => 33
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => the
            [1] => 38
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => lazy
            [1] => 42
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog.
            [1] => 47
        )
)
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => the\n
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => quick\n
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => brown
            [1] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => fox
            [1] => 16
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => jumped\n
            [1] => 20
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => over
            [1] => 27
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => the
            [1] => 32
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => lazy
            [1] => 36
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog.
            [1] => 41
        )
)
```

Any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Lookbehinds are fixed width, so can't match one or more spaces. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463723/regex-workaround-for-phps-look-behind-fixed-length-assert-limitation) will help

Comment: Not possible. I would just match and then fix the output with some php code. [See demo](https://eval.in/223793)